# Resizing image in html

Tags: html, css

I have created the following html page  : 
https://jsfiddle.net/pensee/pyb1oawt/ 
I am having issue with the Image - **Intro to kittens** 
and the **slide show ones** 
The Intro to kittens image is spanning the whole horizontal line 
and the slide show image is covering the whole page. 
I want to cover it like 1/3 of page nearly and have a horizontal
look.
Examples :

[intro-to-kittens-should-appear-like-this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWfs4.png)
[slide-show-image-should-appear-like-this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtbON.png)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.promo_banner {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.logo img {
  max-width: 205px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.nav .menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.nav .menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav .menu li.active {
  color: green;
}
.nav .menu li:hover {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.contents_title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="promo_banner">
      <div class="promo_banner__content">
        <p>
          <strong>Our Guide on Caring for Your Furry Feline Friend</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="promo_banner-close"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="top_bar clearfix">
      <ul class="social_icons">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />

        <div class="container">
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.facebook.com"
              ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.instagram.com"
              ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a
          ></span>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="logo text-align--center">
      <a href="https://store.linefriends.com" title="LINE FRIENDS INC">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/rQ70P05/logo.jpg"
          class="primary_logo lazyloaded"
          alt="LINE FRIENDS INC"
      /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu center">
          <li>
            <span>HOME</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>All About Kittens</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Feeding Your Kitten</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align: center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="contents_title">
      <h2><fontsninja-text>Kittens</fontsninja-text></h2>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shg-rich-text shg-theme-text-content">
      <p>
        <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: inherit"
          >Cuteness Overload</span
        >
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="slide-show.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?
I have added these codes to fix sizing problems

```
div.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
} 
div.mySlides img{ 
  width: 40% !important;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.promo_banner {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
} 
div.mySlides img{ 
  width: 40% !important;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
div.logo img {
  max-width: 205px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.nav .menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.nav .menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav .menu li.active {
  color: green;
}
.nav .menu li:hover {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.contents_title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10px;
}
.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="promo_banner">
      <div class="promo_banner__content">
        <p>
          <strong>Our Guide on Caring for Your Furry Feline Friend</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="promo_banner-close"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="top_bar clearfix">
      <ul class="social_icons">
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />

        <div class="container">
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.facebook.com"
              ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a
          ></span>
          <span
            ><a href="https://www.instagram.com"
              ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a
          ></span>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="logo text-align--center">
      <a href="https://store.linefriends.com" title="LINE FRIENDS INC">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/rQ70P05/logo.jpg"
          class="primary_logo lazyloaded"
          alt="LINE FRIENDS INC"
      /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu center">
          <li>
            <span>HOME</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>All About Kittens</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Feeding Your Kitten</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/PDjJ4rd/small-but-fiesty.jpg"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align: center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="contents_title">
      <h2><fontsninja-text>Kittens</fontsninja-text></h2>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shg-rich-text shg-theme-text-content">
      <p>
        <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: inherit"
          >Cuteness Overload</span
        >
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="slide-show.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I am just looking for image resizing. But posted full code so that it gives full context. Not sure if I should have given only the relevant sections. But the relevant sections are quite clear once you open it as a webpage.

Comment: Okay but as a result my solution fixed your problem or not? That's different snipped than your snipped if you run

Comment: Thanks yeah That's much better. If you can help me with one last thing that would be great. If you see this website - `https://store.linefriends.com/` Under the slide-show there is the Text `New Collections` and under it `Cuteness overload` I am trying to make it similar to it. If you see my text also has `cutness overload` under the `Kittens` text but its not styled as in the website. The gap between the two is more than it should be

Comment: Also when you have to justify something to center is it always neccessary to use flex just as you used in the logo ? or can it be done without flex ?

Comment: I edited my answer and now it should work as you want. If your problem solved please choose it as accepted answer. Justify-content is a feature of flexbox so you would need flexbox to use it. Enjoy!